# Problem downloading and installing Google Chrome on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I'm on Xubuntu 22.04 at the moment trying to download Chrome, but when I run

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

through the terminal i get a 404 not found message.
I tried downloading it from the site directly but the same thing happens and I get the exact 404 not found prompt.
What should I do?.

Comment: Did you try downloading the deb file with Firefox?

Comment: Indeed you can just download it, double-click (opens Ubuntu Software) and install, no need to do it in terminal with wget. But you can and the URL is correct. Do you have internet connection?

Comment: Yes I did try downloading it from Firefox but it would direct me to a blank page with a 404 not found message.

Comment: could u provide a screenshot of the command on your terminal please?

Comment: *I did try downloading it from Firefox but it would direct me to a blank page with a 404 not found* It's a problem on your side, i.e. your internet service. Again, I just tested the download and it works perfectly fine. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: It sounds like you're on a controlled network to me, and your network is preventing the `wget` or download from occurring, ie. you have a network issue & need to change network, use a VPN or get around specific issues with your current network (*are you in a school? workplace with controls etc*)

Comment: Xubuntu 20.04 is on topic on AU, as long as the question also works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.